# Word for lying lazily in bed?

Tags: synonyms

There is a word used specifically for lying relaxed in a bed or someplace comfortable, stretched out and not wanting to move from that position. Problem is, I can't remember what the word is called, just knows it starts with the letter "p".  Help a brotha out (:

Comment: "Prone" might be suitable, but isn't specific to beds. "Plastered" comes to mind ;-)

Comment: I'm tempted to say *procrastinate*, except it's not specific to a lying position.

Answer (score -1):

***Have a [lie-in](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lie+in)*** is an expression that conveys the meaning you are referring to:

> A prolonged stay in one's bed in the morning. Often hyphenated. 
>   Primarily heard in US.
>
> - Your mum's having a lie in this morning, so we need to be extra quiet downstairs. I love having a long lie-in on Sundays.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: No native speaker of American English would say this

Comment: This seems much more British. The example sentence even uses "mum" instead of "mom". AmE rarely if ever uses the "having a" construction.